# Erro - Jquery não carrega função corretamente

Tags: jquery

O erro apareceu após eu tentar adicionar o .click(function())
[image]

Como é possível ver na imagem acima, o resultado não é o esperado, que seria que o h1 ficasse da cor laranja, com um fadeIn, e uma função onclick.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('h1')
.css("color","#f66")
.hide()
.delay('1000')
.fadeIn("slow")
.text('Teste')
.click(function()){
    $('body').css("background","#C30")
    $('h1').css("color","#fff");


});
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>Teste aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#" class="link 2">1</a>    
<a href="#" id="link3">1</a>
```

Eu já verifiquei, e a CDN está correta. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Não está indo pelo caminho certo não amigo!

Comment: O erro só aconteceu após eu adicionar a parte do .click(function)()), porque antes estava funcionando corretamente, com o fadeIn e o color funcionando

Comment: Bom eu sinceramente não entendi o que você quer fazer. Mas no código você está cheio de **`});`** sobrando!

Comment: É apenas um teste amigo, estou apenas testando o uso do Jquery, por isso que eu coloquei tanta coisa, vou editar e mostrar o código completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é apenas um erro de sintaxe. Há um parênteses indevido nesta linha:

```
.click(function()){
                 ↑
```

O correto seria:

```
.click(function(){
```

Com a correção tudo funciona como previsto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('h1')
   .css("color","#f66")
   .hide()
   .delay('1000')
   .fadeIn("slow")
   .text('Teste')
   .click(function(){
       $('body').css("background","#C30")
       $('h1').css("color","#fff");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Teste aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#" class="link 2">1</a>    
<a href="#" id="link3">1</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 2):

**Basta rearanjar seu script**

inicialmente setar a cor do h1 é incoerente pois já entra hidden.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('h1').css("color","#f66");
        $('h1').hide();
        $('h1').delay(1000);
        $('h1').fadeIn("slow");
        $('h1').text('Teste');

        $('h1').click(function(){
            $('body').css("background","#C30");
            $('h1').css("color","#fff");
       });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <h1>Teste aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link 2">1</a>    
    <a href="#" id="link3">1</a>
```